# Error in my first ExtJs 6 application. Ext.app is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am new to ExtJs. 
I have create sample ExtJs app and I am getting error 'Ext.app is undefined' in the console. I am not getting desired output on the screen.

Following is my app.js file and HTML file:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    launch: function () {
        console.log('App created');
    }
}
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <link href="Styles/extjs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the image of project

[image]

Comment: It seems you havent loaded extjs framework related thing in html file.From where you got this example.What is your app.js ?

Comment: Following is my app.js.

Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    launch: function () {
        console.log('App created');
    }
}
)

Comment: Hi Tejas, 
I got the example from following URL.

http://teknopoint.us/install-extjs-and-creating-sample-app/

Comment: can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Did you see ext-debug.js is loaded in network tab ? You will need extjs framework to load for your code.

Comment: The article is 6 years old and no longer relevant. Follow the getting started guide in the Sencha docs.

Comment: Thanks Tejas and Evan. 
But the files which I have added are sufficient or not ?
Do i need to add any more files ?

Comment: Hi Evan, 
I followed getting started guide of ExtJs 6 and I am still getting the same error. 
:(

Comment: Use ext-all-debug.js instead

Comment: Hi Fabio, getting same error using ext-all-debug.js

Comment: I am just using the javascipt files here, do I need to install anything before start using the ExtJs ?

Answer (score 0):

The ext-debug.js script only includes the types under the root Ext namespace. Try including ext-all-debug.js instead.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring Ext.app.Application as per for the following forum thread.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?304087-ext-debug-receiving-Ext-app-setupPaths-undefined-Full-source-debugging

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.app.Application'
], function() {
    Ext.application({
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reference the framework's `bootstrap.js` (while in debug mode) in order the have `Ext.Loader` (aka the mini-loader) available; after compiling, it's source code + framework concatenated into a single file. loading the pre-built `ext-all.js` or `ext-all-debug.js` is not exactly how this framework works (despite it may solve your problem); better use [SenchaCmd](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/), else you'd be lost with dependencies easily. here would be one [example](https://github.com/syslogic/extjs-nvd3-charts) (mine) for an `ExtJS` project; eg. see the [Application.js](https://github.com/syslogic/extjs-nvd3-charts/blob/master/app/Application.js) and compare that to the live example's `application.js`, to see what I mean.